# I can not receive cookies from server when i call api form angular but when i test on postman its can.(mybackend is NestJS)

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, jwt

This is my backend code of login

```
async loginUser(loginUserDTo : LoginUserDto, response : Response): Promise<any> {
    let responseC = new ResponseStandard()
    let user = await this.userModel.findOne({where: {email: loginUserDTo.email}})
    const jwt = await this.jwtService.signAsync({id: user.id})
    response.cookie('jwt', jwt, {httpOnly: false })

    if (!user) {
        responseC.error_code = "400"
        responseC.error_message = "Invalid User"
        throw new BadRequestException('Invalid User')
    } 
    if (!await bcrypt.compare(loginUserDTo.password, user.password)) {
      responseC.error_code = "400"
      responseC.error_message = "Password not correct"
      throw new BadRequestException('Password not correct')
    }
    else {
        responseC.success = true
        responseC.result = user
    }
    return responseC
  }
```

when i test this on postman its work normally

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6NLQ.jpg)

This is my frontend code. when i call it from this. i can not receive cookie

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor( private http:HttpClient){}
  onSubmit(data:any)
  {
     this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/users/login',data,{observe: 'response', responseType: 'json',withCredentials: true})
     .subscribe((result)=>{
      console.warn("result",result)
    })
    console.warn(data)
  
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKq8J.jpg)

I want it to receive normally like I test it on backend

Comment: what framework are you using for the backend code?

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell about that. I use nestjs

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be related to CORS. You mentioned it is nestjs, here is their documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors

Basically, the cookies are rejected if your cors headers are not correct. In that case you would probably have an error in the browser console about Access-Control-Allow-Origin not being correct.

In nestjs I believe what you want is

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { 
cors: {
 origin: ["angular url"],
credentials: true
} 
});
```